# What is correct means of upgrading a solr schema on running system?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

We're using Solr 7 and running in production via docker images. I was reading the https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/schema-api.html guide to using the API and trying it to add a new field to an existing schema on a local instance when I got the following error:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":9},
  "errors":[{"errorMessages":"schema is not editable"}]}
```

So I wondered what is the best practice approach for updating a schema on a live system. Is it a case of editing the **schema.xml** on each node and restarting in turn?

Comment: You changed the schema from managed-schema to schema.xml (that is, using ClassicIndexSchemaFactory) ? If so, then you cannot use the schema API to change it. If you are using Solr 7 in a distributed setting then is better to use managed-schema instead of schema.xml.

But if you are using the ManagedIndexSchemaFactory then check if <bool name="mutable"> is true.

https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/d6d2e3b2e30b600b9f550abf9414743d628cbcf0/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/schema/SchemaManager.java#L82-L86

Comment: @eribeiro thanks for the info there. I found those settings in solrconfig.xml and as you suggest we are indeed using ClassicIndexSchemaFactory. I'll need to check with our team on why we've implemented it that way, but in the interim I'd love to understand two things: 1) why is the rest API considered the best way to update the schema in a distributed system and 2) given our current setup, i.e. that we are using ClassicIndexSchemaFactory and using docker as our deployment mechanism, is updating the schema.xml and redeploying the containers the best approach given undesired configuration?

Comment: Also, rather than answering as a comment, can you make this an answer so I can award the correct answer to you?

Comment: 1) "When running in SolrCloud mode, changes made to the schema on one node will propagate to all replicas in the collection." at https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/schema-api.html

2) you should update each schema.xml and reload the cores on each instance. If you change the schema almost certainly you'll need to reindex the data.

Comment: So, you don't need to reboot the containers, you need to reload the cores on each instance. This can be done via Shell/python script through Solr HTTP Rest like API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use managed-schema (ManagedIndexSchemaFactory) or classic schema.xml (ClassicIndexSchemaFactory), defined in the solrconfig.xml. The schema.xml doesn't allow change the schema via API. Also if using 
ManagedIndexSchemaFactory check if subtag name="mutable" is false, if so the change is disabled. If you are using SolrCloud and recent versions of Solr it is recommended to use managed-schema.